# Change cursor while AJAX running

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a field and a button that execute a search using AJAX. I would like the cursor to change to "progress" while the search is running and then back to "default" when it's complete.

```
function getFromFile(pFilePath, pFileName, pParseType) {
    var vCompletePath = pFilePath + pFileName;

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){$("body").css("cursor","progress");},
        type: "GET",
        url: vCompletePath,
        dataType: pParseType,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data retrieval was successful!");
            aReturnedContent = data;
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Data retrieval was unsuccessful!");
        },
        complete: function(){$("body").css("cursor","default");}
    });
}
```

I've tried a few things (including the beforeSend and complete settings), but nothing works. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Change `$('body')` to `$('body *')`. Instead you should just add a class and have the styles set in CSS

Comment: I totally get the CSS comment and will add that once I get the functionality working. Unfortunately, changing to $('body *') didn't work; I still just have an arrow while it's processing.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS too? Because ideally your code should work.

Comment: may need to add invisible modal on top everything, and target  it

Comment: I'm not sure what "invisible modal" means, could you expand? And yes, I could post more of the code, but there's a lot going on. What exactly would you like to see?

Comment: i meant absolute div across the whole screen with high z index;, but there shouldn't    be anything overwriting the cursors css, do a test in chrome tools;

Comment: I just tried a few things and it worked, so I was wondering could it actually be working but your AJAX is just returning so fast you don't realize it?

Comment: I tried testing this by including the code that turns the cursor to "progress" but removed the code that sets it back to "default" and it never becomes "progress".

Comment: I also tested to see if "progress" works at all by including it in the css for "body" and it does work (appears as arrow with blue spinning circle).

Comment: Update to two comments ago: I accidentally only removed the return to "default" from the error function. By removing it from the success function as well it now behaves as follows: execute search, AJAX runs to retrieve content, cursor changes just as the AJAX completes. Which makes it practically useless. I need it to change before the AJAX starts so that it indicates that things are happening to the user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your cursor like this (same at a loader in page) :

```
function getFromFile(pFilePath, pFileName, pParseType) {
    var vCompletePath = pFilePath + pFileName;

    $("body").style.cursor = "progress";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: vCompletePath,
        dataType: pParseType,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data retrieval was successful!");
            aReturnedContent = data;
            $("body").style.cursor = "default";
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Data retrieval was unsuccessful!");
            $("body").style.cursor = "default";
        }
    });
}
```

if didn't work in jQuery :

```
function getFromFile(pFilePath, pFileName, pParseType) {
    var vCompletePath = pFilePath + pFileName;

    document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: vCompletePath,
        dataType: pParseType,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data retrieval was successful!");
            aReturnedContent = data;
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Data retrieval was unsuccessful!");
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Neither version worked. The cursor remained as either an arrow or insert (based on if I pressed Enter or clicked Submit). It never changed to 'progress'. Any ideas as to what may be preventing these methods from working?

Comment: Your body is a 100% of your page ? Because i test with a simply button it works

Comment: Yeah, it's <html><head></head><body><other divs/></body></html>

Comment: When you press F12 your body on console cover all page ?

Comment: When I press F12, the console comes up about halfway through my "mainDiv" which is in the body.